# Filtering on an alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

Why doesn't the following query work? Mysql complains about z - can't I use an alias in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT x + y AS z, t.*  FROM t
WHERE 
x = 1 and
z = 2
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'z' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to
>   column aliases in a WHERE clause. This
>   restriction is imposed because when
>   the WHERE clause is evaluated, the
>   column value may not yet have been
>   determined. For example, the following
>   query is illegal:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
> ```

Try this, instead:

```
SELECT x + y AS z, t.* FROM t WHERE x = 1 HAVING z = 2;
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But _why_ does that work? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291031/what-is-the-semantic-difference-between-where-and-having

Comment: The HAVING-clause will have MySQL do a second filtering pass on the result from the query (including any aggregate results) and then only keeps results matching the HAVING-clause.

Answer (score 4):

You should be aware that the usage of the HAVING clause *without* a GROUP BY clause is a non-standard extension of MySQL and won't work in other databases.

If you want this to be portable, you need to use a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT (x + y) AS z, t.*  
  FROM t
  WHERE x = 1 
) t2
WHERE z = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use having clause:

```
SELECT (x + y) AS z, t.*  FROM t
WHERE 
x = 1 
having z=2
```