# What is the semantic difference between WHERE and HAVING?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, having

Let's put `GROUP BY` aside for a second. In normal queries (without `GROUP BY`), what is the semantic difference? Why does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290862/filtering-on-an-alias-in-mysql/4290898#4290898) work? (put an alias in a `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`)

Answer (score 3):

`HAVING` operates on the summarized row - `WHERE` is operating on the entire table before the `GROUP BY` is applied.  (You can't put `GROUP BY` aside, `HAVING` is a clause reserved for use with `GROUP BY` - leaving out the `GROUP BY` doesn't change the implicit action that is occurring behind the scenes).

It's also important to note that because of this, `WHERE` can use an index while `HAVING` cannot.  (In super trivial un-grouped result sets you could theoretically use an index for `HAVING`, but I've never seen a query optimizer actually implemented in this way).

Comment: @ripper234: If you look at the query analyzer for that query, and a GROUP BY query, you'll notice they're oddly identical (except for loading up the actual expression value) - you're still paying the "penalty" of GROUP BY - O(n) iteration over every element in the result set to apply the HAVING clause.

Comment: @ripper234: not requiring a group by is a MySQL extension to the GROUP BY operator and is equivalent to using a GROUP BY with a sub-set of the non-aggregated columns. Look at this article that explains what is going on in the back if you have a "partial" group by: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291280/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-having-on-alias-vs-not-using-having

Answer (score 2):

MySQL evaluates the query up to and including the `WHERE` clause, then filters it with the `HAVING` clause. That's why `HAVING` can recognize column aliases, whereas `WHERE` can't.

By omitting the `GROUP BY` clause, I believe you simply tell the query not to group any of your results.

Comment: That's not a semantic difference (or at least, I don't understand this semantic). That sounds like an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Very broadly, `WHERE` filters the data going into the query (the DB tables), while `HAVING` filters the output of the query.

Statements in the `WHERE` clause can only refer to the tables (and other external data sources), while statements in the `HAVING` clause can only refer to the data produced by the query.