# Is there a performance difference between HAVING on alias, vs not using HAVING

Tags: sql, mysql, database, having

Ok, I'm learning, [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290862/filtering-on-an-alias-in-mysql/4291128#4291128) by [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291031/what-is-the-semantic-difference-between-where-and-having/4291055#4291055), about what `HAVING` means.

Now, my question is if these two queries have difference performance characteristics:

**Without HAVING**

```
SELECT x + y AS z, t.*  FROM t
WHERE 
x = 1 and
x+y = 2
```

**With HAVING**

```
SELECT x + y AS z, t.*  FROM t
WHERE 
x = 1
HAVING
z = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be different - (1) is expected to be faster.

Having will ensure that first the main query is run and then the having filter is applied - so it basically works on a the dataset returned by the (query minus having).

The first query should be preferable, since it does not select those records at all.

Comment: If this is true, then I'm again forced to ask why can't I use aliases in the where clause. This is a design decision by someone (the authors of mysql?), that forces me to either write more complicated queries or lose performance.

Comment: Aliases are assigned after the result set is returned. That is why they are available in having clause but not in where clause. In SQL server, you could use derived columns, but I am not aware of any such options in Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

HAVING is used for queries that contain GROUP BY or return a single row containg the result of aggregate functions. For example `SELECT SUM(scores) FROM t HAVING SUM(scores) > 100` returns either one row, or no row at all.

The second query is considered invalid by the SQL Standard and is not accepted by some database systems.

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged 'mysql'

Comment: Sure, but it is also tagged sql.